# How to implement the cucumber data table for different JSON post using java?

Tags: automated-testing, cucumber, rest-api

I'm trying to post different json body , but same set of set of steps

ie., request builder, header and assertion.

Is it possible to implement cucumber data table for different set of json?

Answer (score 1):

Have you look at [this](https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/07/12/test-your-api-with-cucumber-and-json_spec)? Maybe it gives you some idea.
It is combination of Cucumber and JSON_SPEC.
Otherwise you can always load different data from different JSON files as resources.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) I think it is exactly what you are looking for, and it has some pretty advanced data-driven testing capabilities that go beyond what the default Cucumber `Examples` tables give you.

Here is one advanced example: [dynamic-params.feature](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/search/dynamic-params.feature)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use a Cucumber DataTable, but you would have to implement the step to create the JSON String / object from your DataTable.
Here's a blog that can help you there: http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2014/06/30/cucumber-data-tables

Rather than using JSON Strings, consider using a domain object with a library like Jackson to generate the JSON from the object for you. This makes your code much cleaner (easier to maintain, less error-prone)

There are several frameworks that can help you post the HTTP request. Karate is one such framework, which I personally haven't used. Another is RestAssured, which I am using atm and found quite easy to get started with. There should be plenty of examples/tutorials on how to use it.

Good luck!